# How to make a dropdown show up properly outside of a container which has a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I have a dropdown that I would like to display properly outside of the container which has a horizontal scrollbar. It is currently "buried" inside the container.

See demo: https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/EdYgXr

The container has a hard restriction of:

```
width: 300px;
overflow-x: auto;
```

My only requirement is that the solution should works with the horizontal scroll bar, and preferably no javascript.

- See attempt 1: https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/KGPNpb. This version sort of works when we don't scroll. It beaks as soon as we scroll.
- See attempt 2: https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/KGPNaE. This version breaks the scrollbar entirely

Comment: I don't think this would be possible just with css, since your parent container has the overflow-y: none. The children will not be able to override them. You could get this done by using a bit of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This article has a pretty good explanation of the issue and offers a workaround, although it still requires JS to properly position the submenus: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

But in your case it seems enough to just remove `position:relative` from `.dropdown` - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGPWEx

This is due to the fact that even absolutely positioned elements just assume the position they would have in normal flow, when the “coordinates” (top, left, ...) aren’t explicitly specified, but left at their initial default of `auto`.

(This won’t work though, if *any* of the ancestor elements further up the tree is positioned - like if you add `position:relative` for `.container` in your example, it breaks again. In such a case, I think you might have to go for the “full” workaround as outlined in the mentioned article.)

Comment: Thanks. I think removing `position:relative` is the same approach I tried to take in my attempt 1 above. However it breaks as soon as we scroll.

Comment: Ah, didn’t scroll, so I didn’t notice that :/ Well then you might need to go for a JS solution, I think.